# Kill Meteor On Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, meteor

I will try to post calmly but really I want to throw my computer out the window.

I have resized my digital ocean droplet, and all of a sudden there is a second instance of meteor running, with a much older version, but I can't control it from meteor up.

So mup stop doesn't do anything.

Additionally, I have ssh'd into the server and started to kill every port that I can find that's related to mongo, but the bastard won't die! It will stop for a second, and then it restarts on a separate port. I can't figure out how to stop this damn thing.

Here are some things I've tried

```
     -9 1375
 lsof -Pi | grep LISTEN
 kill -9 1304
 kill -9 3306
 kill -9 1300
 kill -9 1304
 sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:80`
 sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:27017`
 sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:3306`
 sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:27017`
 netstat
 sudo netstat -lnp
 kill 3306
 kill 69671
 kill 9341
 kill -9 69671
 kill -9 443
 kill -9 9227
 sudo netstat -tupln
 sudo kill -15 1070
 sudo kill -15 1025
 sudo kill -15 6968
 sudo netstat -tupln
 sudo kill -15 7140
 sudo kill -15 7110
 sudo kill -15 7115
 sudo netstat -tupln
 lsof -i :80
 sudo netstat -peanut
 sh killport 9001
 sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:80`
 netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
 sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:3306`
 netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
 kill 3306
 sudo netstat -lpn |grep :8080
 sudo netstat -lpn |grep :3306
 kill -9 3306
 netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
 sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:80`
 netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
 sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:587`
 pkill mysqld
 pkill node
 ps faux
 pkill root

 ps faux
 /usr/bin# initctl
 kill -9 processid
 kill -9 1304
 kill -9 783
 kill -9 1
 kill -9 8295
 kill -9 8296
 kill -9 8298
 ps faux
 mongo --help
 kill -9 `ps ax | grep node | grep meteor | awk '{print $1}'`
 kill -9 ps ax | grep node | grep meteor | awk '{print $1}'
 kill -9 `ps ax | grep node | grep meteor | awk '{print $1}'`
 kill -9 `ps ax | grep node | grep meteor | grep -v atom | awk '{print $1}'`
 sudo killall -9 node
 kill `ps ax | grep '[m]eteor' | awk '{print $1}'`
```

I don't know what else I can possibly try, but maybe someone could help me out so I don't go insane. My site is live and sending people to the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this (same with meteor);

```
pskill mongod or pkill mongod (on some systems)
```

When SIGTERM reaches mongod, it will close the database.

Check wether everything is closed with:

```
ps -ef | grep mongod
```

Then shutdown by:

```
kill <PID of mongod>
```

Don't use

```
kill -9
```

EDIT:

if nothing helps, than another daemon is starting mongod. U can check the parent PID like this:

```
ps -l -pPID "Enter the PID of mongod"
```

Under ppid you can see the parent pid. Just close this daemon with
    kill 
and everything should be fine.

Or install the tool "pstree" and Enter:

```
pstree -p PID
```

Watch out for chains like A started B and B started C... so in some cases u have to go through the chain to find the solution

Comment: You can even try, meteor reset =)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I can't run pskill for some reason. I get this: No command 'pskill' found, did you mean: Command 'skill' from package 'procps' (main)...

Comment: and then if I just do kill PID of mongo, it will just respawn as a different ID

Comment: In Ubuntu it is called "pkill" I think, are u sure u are killing mongod with "d" at the end??

Comment: yeah I've copied your commands, and when I try with pkill, it doesn't do anything. It doesn't throw errors, but when I re run ps-ef | grep mongod, the processes are still there. Ps I really appreciate your help thus far!

Comment: Read my updatet post again. This should definitely help you out

Comment: thanks for your help, I finally figured out the problem, I posted my solution below for others to see in the future. I really appreciate your help tho.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help someone in the future, so I will post my solution. It was resolved with one line after many days of dealing with this.

This problem is specific to digital ocean and resizing droplets. It turns out somehow the resize activated something called a docker. I'm not very knowledgeable in dockers (since I've never heard about them before), but they basically compartmentalize your server so one section is independent than the other.

So when I resized my droplet, the docker was turned on, which left me no control when I used meteor up.

So the solution was simply to turn off the docker and voila! things are working again.

the magic line:

```
docker stop nameofdocker (name of docker, which in my case is name of my droplet)
```